# Positive definiteness of block matrices of covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

It is known that a proper covariance matrix is symmetric and at least positive semi definite. I wanted to know whether those properties extends to its  block matrices.

[image]

Referring the section from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Block_matrices) above,  $\Sigma$ is symmetric and at least positive semi definite. Do those properties carry over to $K_{xx}, K_{xy}, K_{yy}$ ?

Comment: By $K_{xx},$ $K_{xy}$ and $K_{yy}$ do you mean entries in the dispersion matrix or do you mean blocks of the dispersion matrix?

Comment: Blocks not entries.

Comment: As $K_{XX}$ and $K_{YY}$ can be seen as covariances matrices, the answer is trivially yes. There is no reason for this to hold for $K_{XY}$, and indeed it's not difficult to find counterexamples. Hint: the covariances of variables from $X$ and $Y$ can be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma.** If $K$ is a matrix that is the dispersion matrix of *any* random vector, then $K$ is positive semidefinite.

*Proof.* Suppose $K$ is the dispersion matrix of the vector $x,$ which we may assumed centred. Then $K = E(x x^\intercal)$ by definition. If $a$ is any constant vector, $a^\intercal K a = E(a^\intercal x x^\intercal a)$ and since $a^\intercal x$ is a real number, the random variable $a^\intercal x x^\intercal a = (a^\intercal x)^2 \geq 0$ and $a^\intercal K a \geq 0.$ QED

If a random vector $x$ is now split as $x^\intercal = (x_1^\intercal, x_2^\intercal),$ then $xx^\intercal = \begin{bmatrix}x_1x_1^\intercal &x_1x_2^\intercal\\x_2x_1^\intercal &x_2x_2^\intercal\end{bmatrix}$ and after taking expectation, we see that the main diagonal blocks are dispersion matrices of random vectors, thus positive semidefinite. Off-diagonal blocks need not be squared, thus asking for positiveness is nonsensical in this case, but even if they were squared, you will get that those blocks are of the form $K_{xy} = E(xy^\intercal)$ and the argument in the lemma above simply does not carry over except under special circumstances (i.e. off-diagonal blocks will rarely have any special property).